# Contents on page reveal itself only if I open the inspector window

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-maps

I'm applying a responsive template to an existing web site that uses an MVC architecture in PHP.

In the page that I'm trying to adapt, there must be a google maps map on the left (50% of the width page) and a list of entries on the other half of the page. My problem is that when I open the page, the map is not shown; but, if I open the inspector window in Chrome, Safari or Firefox, the map appears.

I can't figure out the problem. I don't know exactly which pieces of code to include, because the relevant part is very long and complex.
If the reason can't be guessed I'll try to post the code somehow.

I'll post the link to demonstrate the problem: http://immobiliaretest.altervista.org/cerca?sv=list&pr=GR&s=GR&ct=1&cg=1&tp=tutte&cs=1

P.S. The Google Maps script API is included in the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `id="mapView"` doesn't have any fixed height at all and you are giving the map children a `height:100%`. WHen you use `height:100%` you need the parent to have a fixed height in `px`or if you want the parent to have also `height:100%`you, again, needs to give same `100%` to all relative parents till `body`and `html`(both included).

Just add :

```
#mapView {
    height: 500px;
}
```

to better understand what I mean.

Comment: You, sir, saved my day!! Thank you!